# Running a function that renames dataframes per intermediate step, for a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

I have gotten instructions to do an analysis in R with the vegan package (concerning DCA's).

The instructions on a single dataframe are pretty straightforward, but I would like to apply the analysis on a set of dataframes.

I know this can be done with a for-loop or `lapply` or `sapply`, but I have trouble dealing with the fact that each step of the analysis a new extension is added to the name of the dataframe.

**An example below**

Say I have a dataframe `DF`, then it goes as follows:

```
DF.t1 <- decostand(DF, "total")
DF.t2 <- decostand(DF.t1, "max")
DF.t2.dca <- decorana(DF.t2)
DF.t2.dca.DW <- decorana(DF.t2, iweigh=1)
names(DF.t2.dca)
summary(DF.t2.dca)
DF.t2.dca.taxonscores <- scores(DF.t2.dca, display=c("species"), choices=c(1,2))
DF.t2.dca.taxonscores <- DF.t2.dca$cproj[ ,1:2]
DF.t2.dca.samplescores <- scores(DF.t2.dca, display=c("sites"), choices=1)
```

What I want to achieve is to run several dataframes through this analysis without writing it all out separately.

Let's say I have a set of dataframes called "DF_1", "DF_2" & "DF_3" which I want to do this analysis on.

I probably need to put the dataframes in a list, and get all the steps in a for-loop or one of the `apply` methods. 
But how do I approach the problem with the extensions added (.ra, .t1, .t2, .t2.dca, .t2.dca.DW etc.) to the dataframe names?

**Edit:** I need to retain the original dataframes after the analysis, in order to do follow-up analysis on them.

Comment: Do you need to retain all of those different data frames after you are done with the loop?

Comment: @Elin Yes, this analysis is performed prior to a fork; it determines which of the two follow-up analysis (CCA or RDA) should be used on the dataframes, based on scores. The follow-ups are similar in structure to this analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a very limited amount of data frames, I would not advise to define ca. 8 new objects for each data frame in the global environment as this can become very messy.

One approach you might consider is creating a nested list where the first level is the data frame and the second level are the modified data frames.

```
# some example data sets
DF1 <- mtcars
DF2 <- mtcars*2
DF3 <- mtcars*3

all_dfs <- list(DF1 = DF1, DF2 = DF2, DF3 =DF3)

some_stuff <- function(df) {
  DF.t1 <- decostand(df, "total")
  DF.t2 <- decostand(DF.t1, "max")
  DF.t2.dca <- decorana(DF.t2)
  DF.t2.dca.DW <- decorana(DF.t2, iweigh=1)
  names(DF.t2.dca)
  summary(DF.t2.dca)
  DF.t2.dca.taxonscores <- scores(DF.t2.dca, display=c("species"), choices=c(1,2))
  DF.t2.dca.taxonscores <- DF.t2.dca$cproj[ ,1:2]
  DF.t2.dca.samplescores <- scores(DF.t2.dca, display=c("sites"), choices=1)
  return(list(DF.t1 = DF.t1, DF.t2 = DF.t2, 
              DF.t2.dca = DF.t2.dca,
              DF.t2.dca.DW = DF.t2.dca.DW, 
              DF.t2.dca.taxonscores = DF.t2.dca.taxonscores, 
              DF.t2.dca.taxonscores = DF.t2.dca.taxonscores
              ))
}

nested_list <- lapply(all_dfs, some_stuff)

# To obtain any of the objects for a specific data.frame you could, for example, run
nested_list$DF1$DF.t2.dca.DW
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked and I think I get why it works. What do you mean exactly with your first sentence?

Comment: Let's say you had 100 data frames and would store 8 objects for each data frame in the global environment. Then you would have 800 unstructured objects defined in the global environment and doing any analysis on these 800 objects would be very cumbersome. If you have a nested list, you only have one object defined and can easily do the same operation across data.frames through e.g. `lapply`.  As an analogy, it is like either having 100's of sheets of paper just lying around on the table versus binding them into a book sorted by chapter/topic.